# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine with GeckoDriver and Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I'm using the below python script to login to Fedex tracking service

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextracking/?cntry_code=us&amp;locale=us_en#")
sleep(5)
users = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fxg-field'][1]/input[@class='fxg-field__input-text']")
users.send_keys('test')
passwords = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pswd-input']")
passwords.send_keys('test')
sleep(3)
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='login']")
submit.click()
```

It is not showing exact error but showing these errors:

```
File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
users = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fxg-field'][1]/input[@class='fxg-field__input-text']")
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 393, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element 'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 495, in _request
self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 913, in _send_output
self.send(message_body)
File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 885, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

It works smoothly on Google Chrome but not working with Firefox. Please help me fix this issue.

**EDIT**

Firefox version `57.0.4 (64-bit)`

Selenium version `3.13.0`

geckodriver `0.21.0`

**UPDATE**

The problem is with this website only. I tried other tracking site and they all working with Firefox. This particular site is not working with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code block was near perfect. I took your own code and made couple of tweaks which includes inducing *WebDriverWait* before invoking `send_keys()` on the **USER ID** field as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextracking/?cntry_code=us&amp;locale=us_en#")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='fxg-field__input-text' and @name='USER']"))).send_keys('test')
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='fxg-field__input-text' and @name='PASSWORD']").send_keys('test')
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='fxg-button fxg-button--orange' and @name='login']/span").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshots:

  - `USER ID` and `PASSWORD` fields being filled up:

[image: fedex_1]

- Error due to wrong credentials:

[image: fedex_2]

Comment: @CodeIt The most obivious reason seems OP was attempting to invoke `send_keys()` when a _JavaScript_ / _Ajax Call_ was active. So to accomodate the timespan we have induced _WebDriverWait_ which takes us through. Let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It may be to do with your version of Firefox you're using. Check which Firefox browser versions are supported by selenium. https://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp.

> Support for Firefox is the latest release, the previous release, the
>   latest ESR release and the previous ESR release.
>
> For example Selenium 2.40.0 (released on Feb 19, 2014) supports
>   Firefox 27, 26, 24, 17
>
> Selenium with Firefox can be run on any platform that Firefox supports
>   for those versions, that also allow users to install a custom Firefox
>   extension.

Comment: My version are supported according to https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Answer (score 0):

Inseted of using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fxg-field'][1]/input[@class='fxg-field__input-text']")
```

try with

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(//input[@name="USER"])
```

Comment: Still not working friend. Same error. I'm only having problem with the fedex site. USPS works fine.

Comment: This issue can be resolved by downgrade geckodriver to 0.20.1 ( 64 bits)