# java.io.IOException: Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine with Sendkey() in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, executionexception

OS: Win7 64bit
Browser:Chrome

I'm working on my assignment to test a program with selenium.
I'm using the code provided by the professor,which creates a web-app on my localhost:8080 (So there shouldn't be any connection problem)

```
public void canConenctTwoPlayers() {
    // connect
    //2: missing code
    this.indexPage.connect.click();
    assertThat(this.indexPage.hasText("Successfully connected to the game with unique "), is(true));
    this.indexPage.numberPlayers.click();
    this.indexPage.numberPlayers.sendKeys("2");
    this.indexPage.open.click();
    //second connect
    ChromeDriver second_player = quickConnectAnotherUser();
    //3: missing code
    assertThat(this.indexPage.hasText("The game is now ready to begin"), is(true));
    // quit
    //4: missing code
    disconnectSecondUser(second_player);
    this.indexPage.disconnect.click();      
}
```

In here numberPlayers is the element in the window, where as it name says, input the number of players. But when i use sendKeys, it gives me this exception

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.io.IOException: Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

And when i comment out the sendkeys, the code works well.

```
2018-11-30 13:24:52.749  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.poker.game.PokerSocketHandler        : Opened new session for _fc6yznc.
2018-11-30 13:24:52.749  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ca.carleton.poker.game.PokerGame         : Player is trying to connect _fc6yznc, WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=_fc6yznc]
2018-11-30 13:24:52.749  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ca.carleton.poker.game.PokerGame         : Setting first player as admin:_fc6yznc.
2018-11-30 13:24:52.749  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ca.carleton.poker.game.PokerGame         : Player is being added _fc6yznc, WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=_fc6yznc]
2018-11-30 13:24:52.750  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ca.carleton.poker.game.PokerGame         : Sessions WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=_fc6yznc]
2018-11-30 13:24:52.750  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.poker.game.PokerSocketHandler        : Sending admin message to player.
2018-11-30 13:24:52.750  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ca.carleton.poker.game.PokerGame         : Current number of players is 1. Required number is 4.
2018-11-30 13:24:52.872 ERROR 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.poker.game.PokerSocketHandler        : TRANSPORT ERROR - Error with the network.

java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:282)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:570)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:510)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataControl(WsFrameBase.java:342)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:284)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:130)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:60)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:203)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:663)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.FutureToSendHandler.get(FutureToSendHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:275)
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:127)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:184)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doWriteInternal(NioServletOutputStream.java:94)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doWrite(NioServletOutputStream.java:61)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.writeInternal(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:165)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.write(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:132)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:98)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:80)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:450)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessage(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:338)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:270)
... 16 common frames omitted

2018-11-30 13:24:52.872  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.poker.game.PokerSocketHandler        : Closing session for _fc6yznc with status CloseStatus[code=1000, reason=null].
2018-11-30 13:24:52.872  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.poker.game.PokerSocketHandler        : Disabling all accounts because the admin left.
2018-11-30 13:24:52.873  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] ca.carleton.poker.game.PokerGame         : Sessions WebSocketServerSockJsSession[id=_fc6yznc]
2018-11-30 13:24:52.873  INFO 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.carleton.poker.session.SessionHandler  : Registered _fc6yznc for disconnect.
```

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: Because it is too long so i didn't give the full stack trace. Give me second i will modifiy it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.io.IOException: Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

...implies that the **exception** was raised due to **concurrent execution**.

As per the discussion [ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine with GeckoDriver and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873603/connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-aborted-b) this issue is observed when you attempt to invoke `sendKeys()` when a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) / [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) was still active.

### Solution

The solution will be to induce WebDriverWait for the [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) / [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to complete using either of the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html):

- [**`elementToBeClickable(By locator)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-): An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
- [**`elementToBeClickable(WebElement element)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-): An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

Comment: I will have a look at it later on. Thank you in advance :)